# Search a MySQL Table for a text String, and return if found [SIMPLE]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, linux

I need to use **PHP** to connect to a **database** [confirmed working, I can connect successfully and preform query's on the tables] and search a certain table `[users]`, a certain column within that table `[userinfo1]` for matches on any row to a defined text string `[text1]`. If it finds a match - `echo 1`  If it does not find a match - `echo 0` .

I have tried a few times, but I always seems to fail

I am defining the text string to search the row with  in the URL and using `$_GET =['text1'];`

I confirmed the `$_GET` worked by having it just `echo` straight in for testing.

I cannot find out exactly what query to use to tell it "SEARCH FOR TEXT1 AND TELL ME IF YOU FIND IT"  I thought maybe `mysqli_quer`y

```
($con,"SELECT * FROM `users`"
    . "ORDER BY `users`.`userinfo1` DESC LIMIT 0, 1 ");
```

But all that does is return the first thing it finds in the defined column [userinfo1]

Comment: I downvoted you because I don't think this was an appropriate question for this forum. The question goes back to basic SQL language and simply consulting your SQL notes could have revealed this. I understand you are new to SO, but in future, please try and take that additional effort. On the plus side though, I like that you laid out your question and explained what you want, you you did and what results you got.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM users where userinfo1='YourDefinedtext' ORDER BY userinfo1 DESC
```

[select statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)